# how to set dynamic style in select option in vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, bootstrap-selectpicker

```html
<select v-model="selectcurrency"
   @change="[get(),ready(),setcookie()]"
   class="selectpicker"
   data-live-search="true"
   data-width="120px"
   style="width: 80px;">
      <option v-for="item in currency" :value="item"
         :style="color:'red'" //this style>
            @{{item.symbol}} -- @{{ item.name }}
      </option>
</select>
```

I need the `option` tag with `item.count` where it will color it black if `item.count > 0` and color it red if `item.count < 0`.

Then an image in `option` tag with `item.image` but this doesn't work

```html
data-subtext="<img src='item.icon' class='img img-circle img-thumbnail'>"
```

Comment: You can't style option because it's rendered by OS not browser however you can easly create simple dropdown and style it so it looks exacly like select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Class And Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) with [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

In your situation:

```html
<option v-for="item in currency" :value="item"
    :style="{ color: item.count > 0 ? 'red' : 'black'" //use like this>
    @{{item.symbol}} -- @{{ item.name }}
</option>
```

Comment: tank you worked for me
What do you think of the picture?

Comment: This does not work for me. The styles are overridden by the browser's default styles